# Sampling the transformation matrix

Tags: geometry, transformation

I have a rigid 3D homogeneous transformation matrix 4*4 which includes Rotation (Roll, Yaw and pitch) plus the translation(X,Y and Z).

I want to split this transformation into N small and equal transformations where:

```
T_Orjinal = T.T.T.....T
```

Is it theoretically OK to just extract the angles and translation values from `T_orjinal` and divide them by N then construct the `T` matrix from them? If not, how can I achieve that?

Comment: I may be incompetent but is that a 3-dimensional space or 4-dimensional? Why matrix is 4x4?

Comment: Anyway you can find angle and divide by N or directly get it from the matrix by using formulas for sine cosine of $\frac{\alpha}{N}$

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov it is 3D homogeneous transformation matrix

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov You mean that finding the 3 angles and 3 translation among all axis. Dividing them by N will solve the problem correctly as I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Well, as I said I'm not competent in that kind of things. I guess you can not do it like that. Because translation and rotation are not comutative

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov thank you very much for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subdividing the rotation angle the way you propose works, but the translation is more complicated. W.l.o.g. suppose that $T$ is of the form $$\left[\begin{array}{c|c}R & \mathbf t \\ \hline \mathbf 0^T & 1\end{array}\right].$$ Then $$ T^2 = \left[\begin{array}{c|c} R^2 & \mathbf t+R\mathbf t \\ \hline \mathbf 0^T & 1\end{array}\right] \\ T^3 = \left[\begin{array}{c|c} R^2 & \mathbf t+R\mathbf t+R^2\mathbf t \\ \hline \mathbf 0^T & 1\end{array}\right] \\ \vdots \\ T^n = \left[\begin{array}{c|c} R^n & \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} R^k\right)\mathbf t\\ \hline \mathbf 0^T & 1\end{array}\right].$$ So, $\mathbf t= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} R^k\right)^{-1}\mathbf t_{\text{orig}}$, assuming that the matrix is nonsingular.

Off the top of my head, I can’t think of a way to simplify this sum of powers of $R$. Since $(R-I)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} R^k\right)=R^n-I$, it’s tempting to say that $\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} R^k\right)^{-1}=(R^n-I)^{-1}(R-I)$, but every 3-D rotation has $1$ as an eigenvalue and $R^n$ is a rotation (the rotation part of the original matrix), so unfortunately $R^n-I$ is singular.